# Gitea - How to change the default branch name back to "master"

Tags: git, gitea

I've installed Gitea, and every time I create a new repository it defaults the master branch name to "main", which I find a bit annoying.

Is there a way to make it default back to the normal "master" naming convention? If so how do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When is your version of gitea changing 'master' to 'main' it should also support configuration value *DEFAULT_BRANCH* under the *Repository* section of init file. More details could be found in [official documentation](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/config-cheat-sheet/#repository-repository)

Comment: Put `DEFAULT_BRANCH = master` under the section `[repository]` of the file `/etc/gitea/app.ini`. (The file may be in a different location on your system. I followed the binary install instructions, working on Debian 11.

Answer (score 7):

If modifying the ini config (`conf/app.ini`) file:

```ini
# ...
[repository]
DEFAULT_BRANCH = master
# ...
```

If you happen to be running in a Docker Compose (`docker-compose.yml`) setup:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  gitea:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    # ...
    environment:
      - GITEA__repository__DEFAULT_BRANCH=master
      # ...
```

- Note these are missing all the other settings that are probably needed, just showing where to put the ENV Variable.